# Develop a secured API between Android app and Symfony site

Tags: android, api, symfony, session

I develop an Android app where users can log in and update contents (like their profile, add a comment etc.) on a server. To do that, updates are sent to the server thanks to an API built with Symfony2.

My question is: in general, how can we do to secure API communications between the app and the server?

I found that, is it a good solution?

When user is logged, a key is generated on the server and each time user wants to use the API, he sends the key to be authenticate.
We give to the key a timelife (like 2 hours) and if the key expires, user can't contact API and he is disconnected.

Am I right?

Comment: Your solution sounds viable, I would however urge you to use HTTPS along with it, so noone can sniff the keys. I would use SOAP envelopes (XML) for the data transmission.

Comment: You could also/additionally use OAuth/OAuth2. There are libraries available for Android and Symfony.

Comment: Securing an application it means a lot of stuff. Don't confuse authentication with secure communication. If you want to authenticate an user, I'd like to suggest to use some HTTP schema (basic Auth) or something like OAuth/OAuth2.I-d like to suggest this link: http://symfony.com/blog/going-soa-with-symfony2-a-year-and-a-half-down-the-road . Under authentication" you can find an interesting approach with the Json web token: http://jwt.io/. Regarding "securing communication" https should be a good and simple way to do that.

Comment: Actually your API are secured? How? In general I suggest you OAuth2 protocol.